# Is the destruction of Mishkan Shilo mentioned anywhere explicitly in Tanach?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanach, samuel-shmuel-book-of, chazal

I recall learning through [Sefer Shmuel Aleph](http://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.4/en/Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS?lang=bi) when the Klall Yisrael took the Aron from Mishkan Shilo it was [captured by the Pelishtim](http://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.4.11/en/Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi).

However I do not recall it ever explictily writing when the destruction of Miskan Shilo took place.

Is there a place in Tanach where it is mentioned? I was told by a friend that there is an explicit Chazal discussing such a case.